# Why can't I call toString() on a double value?

Tags: java, inheritance

In Java it was my understanding that every class inherits from Object. But if I call the following code, it balks:

```
Math.PI.toString()
```

It gives the error : "Static Error: No method in double has name 'toString'"

Does this mean that double does not inherit from Object? So what is double then?

Comment: Comment: This does indeed work in C#.

Comment: @PMF I was about to make the same comment. It also works in some other JVM languages such as Scala.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looks like double type variables have no methods. Something wrong with Java or NetBeans?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557900/looks-like-double-type-variables-have-no-methods-something-wrong-with-java-or-n)

Comment: I am surprised you understand what Objects are but not primitives.

Comment: @PMF wouldnt it be `ToString`?

Comment: @Nirk Right, but I thought these details were irrelevant here, as it was a java question anyway ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Math.PI` is `double` and double is primitive type which means it doesn't have any methods. If it would be `Double` then you would be able to call its `toString` method but I don't see any reason for that.

If you want to create String representation of double use

```
String value = String.valueOf(Math.PI);
```

or

```
String value = Double.toString(Math.PI)
```

BTW `String.valueOf(d)` returns result of `Double.toString(d)`.

Answer (score 6):

> Does this mean that `double` does not inherit from `Object`?

Yes.

> So what is `double` then?

It is a primitive type built into the language itself. There are other primitive types like `char`, `short`, `int`, `float`, `boolean`.

Although, the language does provide wrappers built around each of the primitive types, that extends from `Object` - `Integer`, `Character`, `Short`, `Double`, etc.
You can use [`Double.toString(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29) method to get string representation.

Answer (score 3):

No, Math.PI is a double (primitive, not a Double (Object) so it doesn't inherit from Object

Answer (score 3):

That's because `double` is a primitive. It does not inherit from `Object` and doesn't have it's behavior. You can still call `toString()` on `Double` which in turn is an object.
Read more on primitives and objects in Java. [This](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/difference-between-a-primitive-type-and-a-class-type/) might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

`double` is not an object, but a primitive.  Therefore it does not have Object's methods such as `toString()` etc.

There is an Object version of double called `Double` which is an Object wrapper around a `double`.

You can create a Double by calling `Double myDouble = Double.valueOf(primative);`

`Double` also has static helper methods for common operations on primvatives such as toString

Calling `Double.toString(Math.PI);` is probably what you want

Answer (score 1):

`double` is a primitive type, but you can use the Java [Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) class to help.

This should do what you need:

```
Double.toString(Math.PI)
```